# How to run chromium on the the occulus rift dk2 screens?

Tags: chromium, virtual-reality

I have a Occulus DK2. I'm using the newest occulus app 1.1 from the official website. The occulus is working great, I am in the standard room you get spawned in and I can launch the dreamdeck demo and everything works. Now I followed the instructions on how to use the experimental chromium build [here](https://github.com/Web-VR/iswebvrready/wiki/Instructions%3A-Chromium), but chromium shows up on my default pc monitor, instead of the occulus. How do I see the webbrowser on the occulus?
What I did is download the browser, enable the two settings that are specified and then start the browser. Is there something more I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, but yesterday the VR did not recognize the browser, today I started it again and it alteast loaded the chrome.exe. I got an error message and found this [issue](https://github.com/toji/chrome-webvr-issues/issues/68). As mentioned there not all webVR examples work atm. I was trying [this](https://webvr.info/samples/03-vr-presentation.html) but it was not working, but using [example 4](https://webvr.info/samples/04-simple-mirroring.html) it finally worked. I guess it's a little buggy and you need to restart both the device and the browser a few times untill it works. Will leave the question open, if somebody else has a better advice then just to restart many times.

EDIT: I noticed 2 things. 1) It does like it when I plug it in immediately after plugging out my big tv, I don't know why but I tested this and it helped. 2) It does not like it if a WebVR capabable browser already is running when you plug it in. Even when restarting it will not start the browser application, so be sure that the browser is not running while initializing the occulus.

Comment: Could you also please check [this 360 video player demo](https://tools.bivrost360.com/webplayer-docs/simple.html)? Press the Wonder if this bug affects this too...

Comment: Sorry now that I confirmed that webvr is working I unplugged it and stored it away, to be able to use my big tv screen again(only 1 hdmi). Now I'm using the chrome extension that emulates a VR device, because it's much handier. But when I use the device the next time again I will give it a try and drop you a message if that's ok? But I don't know how to reach you?

Comment: Just mention me in the next reply like this: '@Krzysztof Bociurko' and I'll get the message. Thanks.

Comment: @KrzysztofBociurko opening the link in a normal browser works but it does not display anything in the headset. Opening the link with a webvr capable browser just loads the page for minutes and get's stuck in the loading.

Comment: It might be a problem with loading the movie, @Hakaishin. Could you please verify on an [image example](https://tools.bivrost360.com/webplayer-docs/angle-test.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a stupid question, but did you run anything using WebVR? A WebVR enabled browser means that it supports VR content, not that it renders normal content in a floaty VR window.

Try [a demo from WebVR.info](https://webvr.info/samples/03-vr-presentation.html).

Comment: Yes I did that.

Comment: Post a screenshot and a photo of what you see on the Rift, please.